# python selenium for duckduckgo and find url

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to make such a program, first go to duckduckgo.com and search on the search bar Best hotel in india,then find my website link then click the link to my website.

```
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'C:\Users........\geckodriver.exe')

driver.get("https://duckduckgo.com")
time.sleep(10)
search_field = driver.find_element_by_id('search_form_input_homepage')
search_field.clear()

search_field.send_keys('best hotel in india')
search_field.submit()
time.sleep(10)
driver.find_element_by_link_text("More Results").click()
time.sleep(10)
driver.find_element_by_link_text("More Results").click()
time.sleep(10)
driver.find_element_by_link_text("More Results").click()
time.sleep(10)
driver.find_element_by_link_text("More Results").click()
time.sleep(10)

driver.find_element_by_link_text('//my hotel url//').click()
time.sleep(60)
driver.quit()
```

but i'm getting following error

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element:......
```

Comment: What is the link to your website which is to be searched? @Yash

Comment: `time.sleep(10)` is wasteful. You should do instead once at the beginning `driver.implicitly_wait(10)`. Then when you do a find_element, the driver will implicitly wait for *up to 10 seconds* for the element to appear before timing out. But, of course, if the element shows up before the 10 seconds, which it usually does, you do not needlessly wait longer than you have to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See my comment about `time.sleep` being wasteful. There were only 2 pages worth of results so you need to test in a loop that will not cause an exception:

```
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver
#import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'C:\Users........\geckodriver.exe')
driver.implicitly_wait(10)

driver.get("https://duckduckgo.com")
search_field = driver.find_element_by_id('search_form_input_homepage')
search_field.clear()

search_field.send_keys('best hotel in india')
search_field.submit()
for _ in range(4):
    more_results = driver.find_elements_by_link_text("More Results") # note find_elements with an 's'
    if len(more_results) == 0:
        break
    more_results[0].click()
elements = driver.find_elements_by_link_text('//my hotel url//')
if len(elements) != 0:
    elements[0].click()
else:
    print('Could not find my hotel url')
input('pausing...')
driver.quit()
```